# React : why the tasks doesn't appear?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web-applications, state, react-props

and thanks for reading thsi question, i'm new in React and i try to do a tasks app, so i do this.

App.js

```
import React, { Component }from 'react' 
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import TaskForm from './components/TaskForm';
import tasks from './samples/tasks.json'
import Tasks from './components/tasks'

class App extends Component{ 
state ={
  tasks : tasks
}
addTask = (title, description) =>{
  const newTask = {
    title : title,
    description : description,
    id : this.state.tasks.lenght
  }
  this.setState({
    tasks : [...this.state.tasks, newTask]
  })
  console.log(this.state)
}
  render(){
    return(
    <div>
        <TaskForm addTask={this.addTask}/>
      <Tasks tasks={tasks}/>    
    </div>
    )
  }
ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

tasks.json

```
[
        {
            "id": 0,
            "title": "espada",
            "description": "esta es un arma japonesa que bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla",
            "done" : false
        },
        {
            "id": 1,
            "title": "pistola",
            "description": "pistola semi-automatica que sirve para pegar tiros bla bla bla",
            "done" : false
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "title": "ballesta",
            "description": "loren ipsum dolor no se que carajos seguia despues bla bla bla",
            "done" : false
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "title": "sable pistola",
            "description": "sacado de la franquisia de juegos",
            "done" : false
        }
]
```

tasks.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Task from './Task';
import propTypes from 'prop-types';

export default class Tasks extends Component{

    render (){
        return(
            this.props.tasks.map(task => <Task task={task} key={task.id}/> )
        );
    }
}
Tasks.propTypes = {
    tasks : propTypes.array.isRequired
}
```

task.js

```
import React,{ Component } from "react";
import propTypes from 'prop-types';

export default class Task extends Component{
     state = {
        done : this.props.task.done
    }
    styleCompleted(){
       return {
            fontSize : '20px',
            color : this.props.task.done ? 'grey' : 'black',
            textDecoration : this.props.task.done ? 'line-through' : 'none'
        }
    }
    render(){
        const {task} = this.props; // con esta linea extraemos el arreglo que nos stan devolviendo y lo guardamos en otro llamado task        
            return(
                <div style={this.styleCompleted()}>
                    {task.title} -  
                    {task.id} - 
                    {task.description}  
                    <input type="checkbox"/>
                    <button style={btnDelete}>
                      x
                    </button>
                </div>     
            );
    }
}
Task.propTypes = {
    task : propTypes.object.isRequired
}

const btnDelete = {
    fontSize : '18px',
    background : 'red',
    color : '#fff',
    border : 'none',
    padding : '10px 15px',
    borderRadius : '50%',
    cursor : 'pointer'
}
```

taskForm.js

```
 import React, { Component} from 'react';

export default class TaskForm extends Component{ 
    state = {
        title : '',
        description : ''
    }
onSubmit = e =>{
    e.preventDefault(); // if put this line after addTask the page refresh
    this.props.addTask(this.state.title, this.state.description);
}
onChange = e =>{
    console.log(e.target.name, e.target.value);
    this.setState({
        [e.target.name] : e.target.value});
}
render(){
    console.log(this.props)
    return(
        <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>         
            <input 
            name="title"
            type="text" 
            placeholder="write a task" 
            onChange={this.onChange}
            value={this.state.title}/>
            <br/>
            <br/>
            <textarea 
            name="description"
            placeholder="write a description" 
            onChange={this.onChange}
            value={this.state.descirption}/>
            <br/>
            <input type="submit"/>
          </form>
    );
}
  }
```

when i try to add a newTask at the first click don't do anything, but at the second the newTask is added   ( O.o)\ , but just in state don't appear in the UI. any suggest???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `App`'s `render`...

```
render(){
  return(
    <div>
      <TaskForm addTask={this.addTask}/>
      <Tasks tasks={tasks}/>    
    </div>
  )
}
```

...you have:

```
      <Tasks tasks={tasks}/>
```

That uses the in-scope binding (loosely, "variable") `tasks`, not the state property. So it only ever sees the tasks that you loaded from the JSON, since you assigned them to the binding `tasks` in the `import`.

You probably want to render the tasks from `state` instead, e.g.:

```
<Tasks tasks={this.state.tasks}/>
```

or more commonly:

```
render(){
  const {tasks} = this.state;
  return(
    <div>
      <TaskForm addTask={this.addTask}/>
      <Tasks tasks={tasks}/>    
    </div>
  )
}
```

---

You might also want to use the callback version of `setState` when updating the tasks:

```
this.setState(({tasks}) => ({
  tasks: [...tasks, newTask]
}));
```

What you have will mostly work most of the time, but since you're updating state based on existing state, and since state updates are asynchronous and can be batched together, using the callback form is more reliable.

Comment: aaaaaaaaaah,  u right the binding doesn't working, now appears in the UI  THNKS (y)

Answer (score 1):

Problem solution:

```
<Tasks tasks={this.state.tasks} />
```

Also just some advice, try to use setState like this

```js
this.setState({
    tasks : [...this.state.tasks, newTask]
})
```

to this

```js
this.setState((state) => ({
    tasks : [...state.tasks, newTask]
}));
```

More info why here:
https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate

Comment: the same result, the tasks is added in the array  at hte second click, but not in the UI

Comment: have you changed this <Tasks tasks={this.state.tasks} /> ?
@juanfranciscoquiñonesromero